# Radial Gradient on Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have some problem with radialGradient in Canvas from HTML5. I have some lines which i'm painting on canvas, and i want to set gradient on this lines.

This gradient must run along this "path", so my thought was to make radial gradient in x,y of beggining path, to x,y of end of the path, and i have problem with calcucate this two radials. Can You please explain me how to calculate this radials?

I tried with r1 =0, and r2 = distance between x,y start and x,y stop, but this was bad idea.

for example set path x,y to: start(10,10) and stop(100,100) so there we have some simple line, please help me how to set gradient on this

thats my code:

```
var radius = Math.sqrt((XGStop-XGStart)*(XGStop-XGStart) + (YGStop-YGStart)*(YGStop-YGStart));

var lingrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(XGStart, YGStart, 0,  XGStop, YGStop,radius );
lingrad.addColorStop(0, 'red');
lingrad.addColorStop(1, 'yellow');
ctx.strokeStyle =lingrad;
```

Comment: `var lingrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(XGStart, YGStart, radius/2,  XGStop, YGStop,radius );`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Now i tried with (Xstart, Ystart, distance(path), Xstart, YStart, 0) and probably it works good

Comment: Are you sure you need a radial gradient? By the looks of it, I think it is a linear gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might give you what is intended.

```
var midpointX =  (XGStart + XGStop) /2;
var midpointY =  (YGStart + YGStop) /2;
var lingrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(midpointX, midpointY, 0,  midpointX, midpointY,radius );
```